# Why do I keep getting an error response from Volley (Android)?

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm trying to use volley to make a request to [this](http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/help) api (specifically the /BusinessTypes/basic endpoint) in order to get a list of types of catering businesses in the UK, but I keep getting an error.

Initially, I tried to retrieve the data during the onCreate method which is what I thought might have been the problem (however, ideally this is what I want to be able to do). After creating a test button on a blank activity and hooking that up to the code that makes the request, I still have the same problem.

I'm targeting API 21 (Not my choice & can't be changed).

This is the code corresponding to the plain activity with a single button that has id "but".

```
public class BasicActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    final String FSA_EP_T = "http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/BusinessTypes/basic";
    final String FSA_EP_R = "http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/Regions";
    final String FSA_EP_A = "http://api.ratings.food.gov.uk/Authorities/basic";

    Button b;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_advanced_search);

        b = findViewById(R.id.but);

        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                doStuff();
            }
        });
    }

    private void doStuff() {
        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());

        JsonArrayRequest typeRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(
                Request.Method.GET,
                FSA_EP_T,
                null,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.e("businessType", String.valueOf(response));
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Log.e("VolleyErr", "I keep seeing this!!!");
                    }
                }
        ) {
            @Override
            public Map<String,String> getHeaders() {
                Map<String, String>  params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //The api requires me to specify the api version
                params.put("x-api-version","2");
                params.put("accept", "application/json");
                return params;
            }
        };

        typeRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                10000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

        requestQueue.add(typeRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After some playing around I finally realised my problem.

The api endpoint I am using returns a json object which contains a json array, not just a single json array like I assumed it would.

I extracted the array I needed using

```
response.getJSONArray("businessType");
```

where `response` is now a JSONObject.

I assumed an error like this would have shown up automatically in my log but it didn't.

For anyone else having similar problems, I recommend adding

```
Log.e("VolleyError", error.getMessage());
```

to the `onErrorResponse` method.